# How to add new external editor to Shotwell

Tags: shotwell

In shotwell, it is possible to set external editors that can be used to edit pictures. One can choose from a list of installed programs like e.g. Gimp and ImageMaverick on my system.

However, I would like to use Adobe Photoshop, which I just managed to install using PlayOnLinux. I already created a *.desktop file and it runs perfectly when I start it from the Unity launcher.

My problem is that Photoshop does not show up as possible choice for an external editor in shotwell. I tried modifying the *.desktop file after studying those of gimp and ImageMaverick but could not get it to work. In particular, I set the Category to Graphics and the MimeType entry to the same as for gimp.

Is there any way I can make shotwell add Photoshop - or any program for that matter - to the list of external editors?

Any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shotwell looks into the list: `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list`

As a test, I added a (non sense) line:

```
image/jpeg=gedit.desktop;
```

Which made `gedit` appear in the list:

[image]

What you should do:

- Make sure your `.desktop` file is in `~/.local/share/applications`
- Open the file `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` (open it with e.g. `gedit`). Add a line to the file, like:

  ```
  image/jpeg=<your_desktopfile.desktop>;
  ```

That should make you able to set your application as an external editor in Shotwell. (You might have to logout / in)

Comment: Thank you very much for this comprehensive answer! Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet to upvote your answer.

Comment: @DanielWeiss perfect! glad it works. Your reputation is fine with me :)